# Dual boot Ubuntu with windows 8

Tags: linux, ubuntu, dual-boot

I have Windows 8 and need to dual boot Ubuntu. I made a new partition from Windows Manager.

My machine is `Dell Inspiron 15R-5537 Laptop`
Windows 8, and I tried to install the latest version 16.04 Ubuntu .

My machine doesn't allow to make partitions more than 4. then when I shrink the new space for Ubuntu I have got unallocated space rather than free space!!!

but when I boot Ubuntu and choose

- Installation Type:Something else here
- I can't select the unallocated space! which is the shrink-ed new partition.
- this option of Add(+) is disabled when I select unallocated space.
  such like following:

[image]

**Then I can't install Ubuntu because I can't select and add partitions for Ubuntu. My installation is stopped at this point**

I'm trying to use How do I dual boot Ubuntu with Windows 8 in a different partition?

Comment: There is a new LTS: http://releases.ubuntu.com/precise/

Comment: What kind of hardware is that (server/desktop/laptop/tablet/…, what model)?

Comment: @Dejan , Is not ubuntu 16.04?

Comment: @Gilles, Dell laptop, please see the updated question.

Comment: Create an empty partition from windows 8 first, then Ubuntu installer should pick it up.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using dual-boot with Windows 8, I should assume you have and need UEFI activated. So, to solve your problem you should use **Ubuntu 12.10 64-bit** or later, and follow the [Ubuntu wiki about UEFI](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI#Installing_Ubuntu_in_EFI_mode):

> To install Ubuntu in EFI mode:
>
> 1. Use a 64bit disk of Ubuntu (32bit installer does not detect EFI)
> 2. Use the last version of Ubuntu. Support for UEFI appeared in 11.10, but has become more reliable in next versions. Support for UEFI SecureBoot appeared in 12.10 and 12.04.2.
> 3. Set up your firmware (BIOS) to boot the disk in UEFI mode.
> 4. Then:
>
>    - nothing special is required if you use the automatic installer of Ubuntu ("Install Ubuntu alongside others" or "Erase the disk and install Ubuntu"). Important: if you have a pre-installed Windows and you want to keep it, do not choose "Erase the disk and install Ubuntu".
>    - if you use the manual partitioning ("Something else"), the difference is that you will have to create and use an EFI partition.

Comment: My problem is earlier when selecting free partition to install Ubuntu
please see the updated question.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you have a blank partition on which to install Linux the installer should pick it up. I couldn't find the error you mentioned `this partition is not rooted`
Can you double check to see that its the correct error message?

Comment: No I don't have this error at all.
please see the updated question.

Answer (score 0):

There is an easy way to make machine dual boot with Windows & Ubuntu. There is an small program called Wubi installer stands for Windows Ubuntu installer. You can use this. You need three things

1. An empty partitioned drive with at least 5GB space.
2. Ubuntu ISO image
3. Wubi installer program

You will get Wubi & latest version of Ubuntu from [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/windows-installer)

Keep Wubi program & Ubuntu ISO image at same path i.e in same folder.

Run Wubi program, it will ask for empty drive name & username & password for Ubuntu root user.
Provide the details & follow the instructions. Ubuntu will get installed in 20 minutes.

& I liked the thing is that you can uninstall Ubuntu from Windows control panel at any time.

I hope it will help you to install  Ubuntu on Windows machine.

All the Best.

Comment: Windows is already installed I want to install Ubuntu now
please see the updated question.